# Is there value in a user profile photo for an e-commerce app?

Tags: mobile, e-commerce, app, profile

I am building an e-commerce app and I wanted to know if there is value in adding a user profile photo? I have seen couple of e-commerce apps that don't use them. So wanted to know which is the best practice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No.

Profile photos only make sense if you want to build some sort of community, or if you want the users to interact with each other, for example if users can buy stuff *off each other*.

If it's about buying stuff from a central source, i. e. from the vendor, only… then profile photos make as much sense as walking into a store and loudly introducing oneself to all the other customers.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Got some clarity from your answer.